# Alter Laravel's default log in method?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I generated authentication controllers and routes using the `php artisan make:auth` command.

I would like to update a field named `last_login` in my database whenever a user logs in.

Comment: Can you share the code that you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've altered the default Auth to provide the ability to convert users' passwords from an old algorithm to bcrypt (i'm refactoring a legacy app).

The way I did it:

in `app\Providers\EventServiceProvider.php`:

```
'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
     'App\Listeners\LogAuth',
],
```

i then added the `app\Listeners\LogAuth.php` file with the following contents

```
<?php
namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Attempting;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Auth, App\User, Hash;

class LogAuth {

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function handle($credentials, $remember, $login)
    {
        // get the user, update the column, save
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This worked great, thanks. I had to make the second and third arguments in your `handle()` function default to `NULL` however.

Comment: depending on the laravel version the function is passed 2nd and 3rd parameters or not. i'm on 5.1 now. i'm glad it worked for you.