# how to redirect in laravel 5 after authenticating particular user

Tags: php, authentication, redirect, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to redirect 2 different types of users on different pages, based on their ID stored in database.

I found the authenticating redirection code in redirectifAuthenticated.php file .  I don't know what wrong I am doing in code to get a successful redirection. below is my code.

```html
public function handle($request, Closure $next){
     if ($this->auth->check()){
          $userId = Auth::id();
          if($userId == '1'){
             return new RedirectResponse(url('/symptoms/view'));
          }else{
             return new RedirectResponse(url('/home'));
          }
     }
     return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: add middelware code in your post

Comment: which middle ware code? authenticate.php or verifycsrftoken?

Comment: just do "return redirect(url('/symptoms/view'));" 
No need to use RedirectResponse class...

Comment: check out my answer on this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34880747/2668477

Answer (score 0):

From your code i can see a redirect loop, logic is not correct if you put your redirection there, you should put redirect in the function where your
user is login, like a function called signin in you LoginController.

and also there have a short way to redirect `return redirect()->url('xxx')`